# Getting an error of Invalid Origin in Appwrite Initial Signup | Docker

Tags: docker, containers, port, appwrite

I have made an Appwrite container in GitHub code space.
Please note that Appwrite is not in localhost, it is deployed in GitHub Code space. And I want to access it globally.

I want a solution of this problem.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `.env` file has 2 environment variables:

1. `_APP_DOMAIN`
2. `_APP_DOMAIN_TARGET`

Would you try changing those to your codespace domain and recreate the containers?

Also, FYI, Appwrite has Gitpod integration so it should spin up quickly and easily with Gitpod.